# Работа с PNG

Tags: png, c++

Здравствуйте!

Тема не новая, но ответа на свой вопрос в сети не нашел.
Такое дело, пишу игру на мобильник. Нужно грузить в мобильник `png` картинки и выводить их попиксельно на экран... Могу открыть файл-картинку на чтение-запись... Но `png` в отличии от `bmp` упакована и в этом проблема.

Я конечно могу распаковать картинку в компе и запихнуть в телефон файл, содержащий массив точек, но он это будет очень затратно(сжатая картинка весит меньше чем распакованная)... Я не могу использовать в телефоне библиотеки типа `openGL` и прочие, но могу в свою программу вставить код разжатия `png`. Может у кого-то есть код, позволяющий добраться до пикселей `png` файла или кто-то видел подобную вещь?

Спасибо.

Comment: под какой мобильник пишете? может там есть стандартные библиотеки?

Comment: А если нет, то наверняка есть исходники libpng

Comment: Да вроде http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/

Comment: И libpng.dll нужен... Что эта за штука-pnglibconf.h. Студия говорит что такого файла нет в проекте, а его там и реально нет

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Не знаю поможет или нет, но можете попробовать скачать Qt, там есть исходники libpng и они вроде компилятся в студии. Может это Вам поможет или как-то натолкнет на мысли)) Кстати может Вам и сам Qt подойдет?

Comment: Не QT не подойдет, но попробую, спасибо.

Comment: @Alerr, а Вы файл INSTALL читали?

Что-то там есть о VS.

А лучше переходите под \*nix.

Comment: Библиотеку получилось собрать, вроде работает... Там строк больше тысячи, может кто знает, есть ли какой-то массив, куда распакованная png записывается?